# Failed to use the local bounding box produced by \foreach and \pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-pic

I was confronted with a problem of `\pic` and `\foreach` in `Tikz`. Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
 pics/abc/.style={%
 code={
 \node {this is some path};
 }
 }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%local bounding box failed
\foreach \i in {1,2} \pic[local bounding box=\i] at (0,\i) {abc};
\draw(1)circle(1);

%local bounding box successful
\pic[local bounding box=3] at (10,4) {abc};
\draw(3)circle(1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I produce the `local bounding box` (1) and (2) using `\foreach` and `\pic`, `\draw(1)circle(1);` will cause error. But when I produce the `local bounding box` (3) directly using `\pic` without `\foreach`, `\draw(3)circle(1);` will be all right. Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need braces and may want to add the `/.expanded` key. I made several additional changes to "modernize" your code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
 pics/abc/.style={%
 code={
 \node {this is some path};
 }
 }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%local bounding box failed
\path foreach \i in {1,2} {(0,\i) pic[local bounding box/.expanded=\i]  {abc}};
\draw (1) circle [radius=1];

%local bounding box successful
\pic[local bounding box=3] at (10,4) {abc};
\draw(3)circle[radius=1];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! You've helped me solve the problem.